# How can I get window.location.href in Nuxtjs V3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to let players join a game via QR Code. Since that game will be hosted on several IP's, i want to dynamically generate the URL.

This is my current workaround in my NuxtJS Vue Component:

```html
<template>
  <input placeholder="copy browser window url into this field" v-model="fullPath" @change="generateQR">
</template>

<script setup>
  const fullPath = ref(null)
  QRCode.toDataURL(fullPath.value + ...
</script>
```

What I want to do is something like:

```html
<script setup>
  // not working phantasy code
  QRCode.toDataURL(window.location.href + ...
</script>
```

When using useRouter() and useRoute()'s `.fullPath` attribute, I still only get the relative path `/` instead of `http://10.16.1.173:3000/`.

---

Full code on GitLab: [pages/index.vue](https://gitlab.com/domezi/kahoot/-/blob/da49ff043c0ab9a0cfaacfa6ea8e766b1722030c/pages/index.vue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check if you are in client side before accessing to 'window' object, you can use :

```
if (process.client) {
      console.log(window.location.href)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
this.$route.query
```

Comment: Syntax is wrong for vue3

Comment: Why don't just parse full path instead using `.split()`?

Comment: @bill.gates this is a totally valid syntax AFAIK. What is the issue with that?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32035227)

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam: There is no link here at all, not anywhere.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk you're right. I guess I flagged it wrongly